# STM32L082xx AES128 CBC Hardware Encryption using ST's HAL

Tags: c, encryption, aes, stm32

Decryption is not working as intended on STM32L082xx.

Here is my attempt: I'm using all zeros as iv and key and all 0x42 for plain text.

If I do the same thing in python I get a different result:
I get

{0x7c,0xA5,0xDA,0xBF,0x97,0x18....}

Note I'm using key and IV which are not influenced by endianness so the parameter CRYP_DATATYPE_8B should not be of influence. I have tested with CRYP_DATATYPE_16B, CRYP_DATATYPE_1B, CRYP_DATATYPE_32B with no success. Any ideas?

I've tried with EBC as well, without success.

```
void TEST_decryption(){

  uint8_t encrypted[128]={0x00};
  uint8_t decrypted[128]={0x00};

  for(int i=0;i<128;i++){
    decrypted[i]=0x42;
  }

  HAL_CRYP_AESCBC_Encrypt(&hcryp, decrypted, 128, encrypted, 10000);


  if(encrypted[0]==0xbf){
    while(1);   //pass
  }else{
    while(1);   //fail
  }

}

uint8_t iv[16]={0x00};
uint8_t userKey[16]={0x00};

/* AES init function */
void MX_AES_Init(void)
{

  hcryp.Instance = AES;
  hcryp.Init.DataType = CRYP_DATATYPE_8B;

  hcryp.Init.pKey = &userKey[0];
  hcryp.Init.pInitVect = &iv[0];
  if (HAL_CRYP_Init(&hcryp) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  __HAL_RCC_AES_CLK_ENABLE();

}
```

Same thing in python:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = binascii.unhexlify('0'*32)
IV = binascii.unhexlify('0'*32)

encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV=IV)
print(binascii.hexlify(encryptor.encrypt(binascii.unhexlify('42'*128))))
```

output:

```
   b'bfdaa57cb812189713a950ad99478879ec40e0761ed6475fca829d311af9ab3c72099b8b728c5145dc58f99d4fd9f0466ea50ca1a42a98560407c8e716e32bab1db3b30baa48939e253343b3a20f519767bdbb0f9083540b0ba14d289673c8129ae4c31855bf8a35d8ee1a22ce26337c2987e46fde5b448d1021682f5999ab49'
```

see for live demo : https://repl.it/repls/ImpracticalWhitesmokeCodec

EDIT:

It was suggested to set the key size to 128bit, this is not possible in this lib:

```
 /**
  * @brief  Writes the Key in Key registers. 
  * @param  hcryp: pointer to a CRYP_HandleTypeDef structure that contains
  *         the configuration information for CRYP module
  * @param  Key: Pointer to Key buffer
  * @note Key must be written as little endian.
  *         If Key pointer points at address n, 
  *         n[15:0] contains key[96:127], 
  *         (n+4)[15:0] contains key[64:95], 
  *         (n+8)[15:0] contains key[32:63] and 
  *         (n+12)[15:0] contains key[0:31]
  * @retval None
  */
static void CRYP_SetKey(CRYP_HandleTypeDef *hcryp, uint8_t *Key)
{  
  uint32_t keyaddr = (uint32_t)Key;

  hcryp->Instance->KEYR3 = __REV(*(uint32_t*)(keyaddr));
  keyaddr+=4U;
  hcryp->Instance->KEYR2 = __REV(*(uint32_t*)(keyaddr));
  keyaddr+=4U;
  hcryp->Instance->KEYR1 = __REV(*(uint32_t*)(keyaddr));
  keyaddr+=4U;
  hcryp->Instance->KEYR0 = __REV(*(uint32_t*)(keyaddr));
}
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the library contains a fixed key size, I'll add the code segement to my question

Comment: Yeah, its for STM32L0 its not a parameter I think thats just for STM32F. But I think I just realized my mistake.. its endiness ... Thanks for the support though

Comment: 0x7c,0xA5,0xDA,0xBF <=> bfdaa57c

Comment: That's ridiculous. Even if it uses words internally the lib call should make sure that the right order of bytes is restored. AES depends on test vectors, the bytes should be in the right order. Check if you don't need to set a specific define for your platform wrt endianess... Note that it is completely valid to answer your own question.

Comment: I've removed my previous comments, happy to vote any answer up.

Comment: If I look at the code I see that the default `CRYP_DATATYPE_32B` says: no swapping. Are you sure that doesn't make a difference? That's one ill defined API that you've got there :( It says that `CRYP_DATATYPE_1B` does "bit swapping". WTF?